# JavaScript Object Accessors returns Undefined during object property checking

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a module scaffolding for my node environments.

```
const environments = {}

environments.staging = {
    port: 3000,
    envName: 'staging'
}

environments.production = {
    port: 5000,
    envName: 'production'
}
```

and when I check every time the current environment returns the current `process.env.NODE_ENV` value

```
const currentEnvironment = typeof(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'string' ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'staging'
console.log(currentEnvironment) //staging or production
```

But, when I'm checking it with my environments objects It always returns `undefined`

```
const environmentToExport = typeof environments[currentEnvironment] === "object" ? environments[currentEnvironment] : environments.staging
console.log(environments[currentEnvironment]) // here returns undefined.
```

**what is the fault in my code?**

Comment: `typeof … == 'string'` doesn't mean that the string value actually is `'staging'` or `'production'`. Look for spelling mistakes and invisible characters.

Comment: [That code works](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/pht7mrc0/) if `currentEnvironment` is `"staging"` or `"production"` as you've said it is. So apparently `currentEnvironment` **isn't** either `"staging"` or `"production"` when you get `undefined` for `environmentToExport`. (Note that capitalization matters, so if you're actually seeing `"Production"` as the string rather than `"production"`, it won't match the property.)

Comment: T.J. Crowder is working. Thank  you